How to format a cell value in Google Sheets with TEXT() and have conditional formatting work as well
I'm trying to apply formatting to a cell value with the TEXT() based on the value of the cell while also having the cell background and text color change with conditional formatting. The issue I'm running into is that it seems that the TEXT() overrides any conditional formatting that would be applied.
This is the function I'm using in the cell:
=IF(Sheet2!A10>999, TEXT(Sheet2!A10, "#,###"), TEXT(Sheet2!A10, "###.##")
It achieves what I'm wanting it to do which is to display a number with a comma and no decimal if the value is greater than 999. If the value is less than 999, it displays a number with a decimal point and two digits to the right of the decimal.
I also have conditional formatting applied to the cell to change the background and text color if the value in the cell is greater than 2,000. The conditional formatting to change the background and text color does not work.
Is there a way to have all of this worked into the conditional formatting? When I try and create a function using custom function under conditional formatting, it doesn't seem to work when referencing a value from a different sheet. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Would you be able to provide your sample sheet, with your initial output, and also your expected output so that we can further help you. You may use this anonymous sheet maker to create your reproducible example without your email being exposed.

Still CF should work. You may also try to force formula to convert text function output to number values by using -- like =--B6>2000

@Patsytalk https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MQeTQhZV6jGnQjDXjieTkANAuWjtr_YtnzZy4MUuHpo/edit?usp=sharing

I believe you can achieve your desired result without any formulas at all by using 'meta instructions' in a custom number format. Apply the following custom number format to your number cells:
[<1000]###.##;[>1000]#,###

You can then use conditional formatting to colour cells >2000 in the standard way because you no longer need to coerce numerical values to text using a formula in  order to achieve the desired format.

Thank you. This answer worked perfectly and was a bit easier for me to understand compared to the other answers. I'm not familiar with the let function referenced above and would need to do some research on it to fully understand what is going on there.


Here's one approach you may test out:
=let(Σ,Sheet1!C5,
 if(Σ>999,query(Σ,"format Col1 '#,###'"),query(Σ,"format Col1 '###.##'")))


PS: @Harun24hr suggestion(in the comments) should also work provided you use the Custom formula setting within conditional formatting

Thank you for your answer, @rockinfreakshow. This answer worked but was a bit above my knowledge of Google Sheets with respect to the function itself. I would need to do a bit of research on the let function to understand what is going on there. The answer from The God of Biscuits was the easiest answer for me to follow along with and also worked.
